# Using preseed (Debian/Ubuntu) to partition both RAID and encryption

Tags: debian, ubuntu, raid, debian-installer, preseed

I am trying to configure a preseed image using RAID + encryption.  I originally wanted to do this *without* LVM, however it does not seem (at least with encryption) that this is possible. I simply want to know if this is even possible via preseed -- that is, to have both RAID *and* encryption partitioned. All the documentation I'm seeing states (from what I can tell) that you can only have either RAID *or* encryption.  I'm not seeing any way to preseed both.

FWIW, here is what I've used for LVM+encryption:

```
### Disk Configuration
d-i     partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf
d-i partman-auto/method string crypto
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
d-i partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name string crypt
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select root-encrypted
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                         \
      root-encrypted ::                                       \
              1000 1000 1000 ext3                                \
                      $primary{ } $bootable{ }                \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ /boot }                     \
              .                                               \
              500 10000 1000000000 ext4                       \
                      $lvmok{ } lv_name{ root }               \
                      in_vg { crypt }                         \
                      $primary{ }                             \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ / }                         \
              .                                               

d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/no_mount_point boolean false
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```

And this is what I've tested that works for LVM+RAID:

```
### Disk Configuration
d-i     partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf
d-i     partman-auto/method string raid
d-i     partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i     partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i     partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i     partman-auto/choose_recipe select boot-root
d-i     partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name string cryptroot
d-i     partman-auto/expert_recipe string        \
           boot-root ::                          \
             1024 30 1024 raid                   \
                $lvmignore{ }                    \
                $primary{ } method{ raid }       \
             .                                   \
             10000 35 20000 raid          \
                $lvmignore{ }                    \
                $primary{ } method{ raid }       \
             .                                   \
             10000 35 20000 ext4            \
                $defaultignore{ }                \
                $lvmok{ }                        \
                lv_name{ root }                  \
                method{ format }                 \
                format{ }                        \
                use_filesystem{ }                \
                filesystem{ ext4 }               \
                mountpoint{ / }                  \
             .
d-i partman-auto-raid/recipe string                                   \
    10 6 0 ext4 /boot                                                 \
          /dev/sda1#/dev/sdb1#/dev/sdc1#/dev/sdd1#/dev/sde1#/dev/sdf1 \
          --layout#n6                                                 \
    .                                                                 \
    10 6 0 lvm -                                                      \
          /dev/sda2#/dev/sdb2#/dev/sdc2#/dev/sdd2#/dev/sde2#/dev/sdf2 \
          --layout#n6                                                 \
    .                               
d-i     mdadm/boot_degraded boolean false
d-i     partman-md/confirm boolean true
d-i     partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i     partman-basicfilesystems/no_swap boolean false
d-i     partman/choose_partition select Finish partitioning and write changes to disk
d-i     partman/confirm boolean true
d-i     partman-md/confirm_nooverwrite  boolean true
d-i     partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```

I suppose, I'm trying to meld the two, and I've tried a few different combinations but not have worked out.  Essentially, I believe you can have only either `partman-auto/method string crypt` or `partman-auto/method string raid` but not both.  Can anyone confirm or deny this for me?  Thanks in advance.